# Why file.read() doesn't reads the 1st line?

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.5

I don't know why, but when I try to read a file with the file.read(), Python doesn't recognizes the first line of the file.. It's an interpreter bug, or it's my fault?

You have a copy of the program here (showing the read result): http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1032832/

This is the code which causes the problem:

```
if wfile.readline() != "#! /usr/bin/env python\n":
    before = wfile.read()
    wfile.seek(0)
    wfile.write('#! /usr/bin/env python\n' + before)
    wfile.close()
    os.chmod(file, 777)
```

The Python version which I use for tests is Python 2.5.1 for iOS (Cydia port). My device is an iPad 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reading the first line of the file with the `readline()` function in your `if`-statement. By the time you get to `read()`, the first line has already been read.

The subsequent `write()` will write what `wfile.read()`  has read.

It looks like you want to check if the first line of the file contains the appropriate `#!/usr/bin/...` line. If not, you want to insert it ahead of the current first line, and then write the original first line below it. This will do it:

```
with open(file, 'r+') as wfile:
   before = wfile.readline()
   if before != "#! /usr/bin/env python\n":
      wfile.seek(0)
      wfile.write('#! /usr/bin/env python\n' + before)
```

This way you save the original first line in the variable `before` for later use.

***Note***: using `with` **will automatically close the file for you** when you are done, or an exception is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

file_name = 'foo.py'
shebang = '#!/usr/bin/env python'

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
if shebang not in lines[0]:
    lines.insert(0, shebang)
    with open(file_name, 'r+') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(lines))

os.chmod(file_name, 777)
```